# Checking filetime from external server

Tags: php, filemtime

I'm trying to check when the file on external server was edited last time.
The function `filemtime()` doesn't work and throws an exception.

```
Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for 
http://examplesite.com/export/export.php?username=***&passwd=***&fileType=xml
```

I think the problem is in the link, because it's not a direct link to the file but to a php script. Does anybody knows how to get around it and get filetime without downloading that file?

Comment: don't try the impossible. (you need an API from the external server to get these infos)

Comment: You can't. most of the `stat()`-related functions do NOT work over http. Doesn't matter if you're pointing a url at the actual file or at a script which handles the file. stat-over-http simply doesn't work.

Comment: HTTP does not provide such a feature. Change protocol.